# Laravel - query for column value in pivot table from relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to make an if statement for a query where I need to check if column `status` is set to `rematch` for players for that quiz in the pivot table `player_quiz`. 
This is how to relationship is set up in the `quiz` model:

```
public function players()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Player', 'player_quiz')->withPivot('status');
    }
```

I am not sure how to do that kind of query, to make it clearer here how it should basically look like:

```
if ($quiz->players()->where('status', 'rematch'))->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
if ($quiz->players()->wherePivot('status', 'rematch')->get()) {
   // Do something
}
```